# can't install react-navigation-stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

hi trying to install react-navigation-stack via this code:
npm install @react-navigation/stack

which is what is written at reactnavigation.org

but after installation i get an error that the @react-navigation/stack
could not be found
and i know it is duo to the failed installation which gives this warn at the end of the command line:

npm WARN react-navigation-stack@2.10.4 requires a peer of react-navigation@^4.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.20.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

i also tried to install react-navigation dependecies as the website says to do so.
but still can't install after that.

Comment: Have you installed it as a dev dependency as well?

Comment: no haven't done that just installed based on what is on the website

Comment: did you install using `npm install react-navigation@^4.1.1`?

Comment: no just did  npm install @react-navigation/native

Answer (score 0):

Try installing an older version of react-navigation, like 4.2.0 or 4.4.1, I use both of them till now and they work perfectly. After that install @react-navigation/stack. If there is still an error, then give the specific @react-navigation/stack@^5.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Install it with
yarn

```
yarn add @react-navigation/stack
```

if it did not work write

```
yarn add @react-navigation/stack@version
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).